# BigQuery - how to change the order of the schema with nested columns when creating a view?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I want to change the schema of the nested on my VIEW.

But BigQuery won't do it because I'm calling the record "productPrice".

Indeed, if I don't call this, I can't keep it nested in my view.

Error Message when i use "productPrice"

```
Column xx  in UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRUCT<type STRING, price DOUBLE, currency STRING, ...>, STRUCT<taxRate DOUBLE, taxType STRING, priceStartDate STRING, ...> at [xx:x]
```

table1

```
productPrice                 RECORD     NULLABLE    
productPrice.type            STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.price           FLOAT      NULLABLE    
productPrice.currency        STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.priceStartDate  STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.taxRate         FLOAT      NULLABLE    
productPrice.taxType         STRING     NULLABLE
```

table2

```
productPrice                 RECORD     NULLABLE    
productPrice.taxRate         FLOAT      NULLABLE    
productPrice.taxType         STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.priceStartDate  STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.currency        STRING     NULLABLE    
productPrice.price           FLOAT      NULLABLE    
productPrice.type            STRING     NULLABLE
```

Request with productPrice

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS
SELECT
 productPrice,
 productPrice.taxRate,
 productPrice.taxType,
 productPrice.priceStartDate,
 productPrice.currency,
 productPrice.price,
 productPrice.type,
from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
 productPrice,
 productPrice.taxRate,
 productPrice.taxType,
 productPrice.priceStartDate,
 productPrice.currency,
 productPrice.price,
 productPrice.type,
FROM table2
```

Request without productPrice

```
CREATE VIEW product_view AS
SELECT
 --productPrice,
 productPrice.taxRate,
 productPrice.taxType,
 productPrice.priceStartDate,
 productPrice.currency,
 productPrice.price,
 productPrice.type,
from table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
 --productPrice,
 productPrice.taxRate,
 productPrice.taxType,
 productPrice.priceStartDate,
 productPrice.currency,
 productPrice.price,
 productPrice.type,
FROM table2
```

Result without "productPrice" in the view

```
type             STRING     NULLABLE    
taxRate          FLOAT      NULLABLE    
taxType          STRING     NULLABLE    
priceStartDate   STRING     NULLABLE    
currency         STRING     NULLABLE    
price            FLOAT      NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  STRUCT(
    productPrice.taxRate,
    productPrice.taxType,
    productPrice.priceStartDate,
    productPrice.currency,
    productPrice.price,
    productPrice.type
  ) AS productPrice
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  STRUCT(
    productPrice.taxRate,
    productPrice.taxType,
    productPrice.priceStartDate,
    productPrice.currency,
    productPrice.price,
    productPrice.type
  )
FROM table2
```